# Can't find out why my display value is always 0

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, return-value, modular

Kelvin to C or F Conversion program that uses functions for our lab. I can't figure out why I keep getting 0 as the output. I think it has something to do with how I've passed/returned values. I may have not caught a return?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


float KtoC(float kel)
{
    kel = - 273;

    return(kel);
}

float KtoF(float kel)
{
    kel = (9 * kel / 5) + 32;

    return(kel);
}

float GetKelvin(float kel)
{
    printf("Temperature Conversion Program\n");
    printf("Please enter a temperature in Degrees Kelvin:");
    scanf("%f%*c", &kel);

    return(kel);
}

char GetConvType(char &ctype)
{
    do
        {
        printf("Convert to Celcius (c) or Fahrenheit (f): ");
        scanf("%c%*c", &ctype);

        ctype = tolower(ctype);

        } while(ctype != 'c' && ctype != 'f');

    return(ctype);
}

float GetConvTemp(float kel)
{
    char ctype;

    ctype = GetConvType(ctype);

    if(ctype == 'c')
    {
        return (KtoC(kel));
    }
    else
    {
        return (KtoF(kel));
    }
}   

void DisplayResults(float x)
{
    printf("This is the temp converted %f", x);

    return;
}



int main()
{
    float kel, x;
    char ctype;

    GetKelvin(kel);
    GetConvType(ctype);
    GetConvTemp(kel);
    DisplayResults(kel);

    return(0);

}
```

Comment: Because you are not using the return value of `GetKelvin(kel);`

Comment: What a weird way to write programs

Comment: Note that `char GetConvType(char &ctype)` is C++, not C.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yeah I know... haven't been at it for long and we're starting with C.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sorry, I forgot to mention our lecturer is using a simpler version of PassbyRef from C++ due to time constraints.

Comment: Tell your lecturer that this won't compile under C. A "time constraint" argument is quite eh...how you call it..?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm saving it as a .CPP so it compiles properly. Thanks though, and yeah, it's my first unit so I don't really have any exp or knowledge to judge whether his reasoning is just or not.

Comment: By the way, KtoC always returns -273.  You should use `kel -= 273` instead of `kel = -273`.

Comment: Note: `return` is a statement, not a function. Don't use parenthesis around the expression, this can result in strange behaviour and/or errors on typos.

Answer (score 0):

```
--- xorg.cpp    2017-05-19 00:48:56.000000000 +0900
+++ x.cpp   2017-05-19 00:50:23.000000000 +0900
@@ -4,19 +4,19 @@

 float KtoC(float kel)
 {
-   kel = - 273;
+   kel -= 273.0;

    return(kel);
 }

 float KtoF(float kel)
 {
-   kel = (9 * kel / 5) + 32;
+   kel = (9.0 * KtoC(kel) / 5.0) + 32.0;

    return(kel);
 }

-float GetKelvin(float kel)
+float GetKelvin(float &kel)
 {
    printf("Temperature Conversion Program\n");
    printf("Please enter a temperature in Degrees Kelvin:");
@@ -39,7 +39,7 @@
    return(ctype);
 }

-float GetConvTemp(float kel)
+float GetConvTemp(float &kel)
 {
    char ctype;

@@ -71,8 +71,7 @@

    GetKelvin(kel);
    GetConvType(ctype);
-   GetConvTemp(kel);
-   DisplayResults(kel);
+   DisplayResults(GetConvTemp(kel));

    return(0);
```

Comment: This question requires an *explanation* of the error, not simply a diff of working code.  Please [edit] to explain what's wrong with the original, and why these changes help.